# C++/C Code::blocks crashes while editing

Tags: crash, ide, codeblocks

I'm not completly sure if it's proper to ask this here, but...

I'm a student forced to work with Code:Blocks IDE on Win7 (64 bits), and it keeps crashing everytime I try and add/edit an #include, I've tried in both C and C++ and I think it's got to do with the editor since it compiles correctly.

Has anybody else had this problem? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking how to fix the problem, or whether or not there exists a way to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Best bet would be to search through the [Code::Blocks ticketing system](http://sourceforge.net/p/codeblocks/tickets/) to see if anyone knows about the problem.

If no-one does, then raise a ticket yourself.

It'd also be a good idea to provide as much information there up front as possible, such as the source files (or enough of them to cause the actual problem), project settings, IDE version, and so on.

That'll get your ticket moving along faster than if they have to chase you for the information.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Jason, I believe it _does_ provide the answer. The question was "is there any way to fix it?". My answer is that, if you have a piece of software that's crashing, the correct way to fix it is to ask the people responsible for maintaining it. This isn't a "why is my code failing?" question, it's a fundamental fault with the development tool itself, one that should be sent to the developers. And I am neither critiquing the question nor requesting clarification.

Comment: Jason, we'll have to agree to disagree on that one, notifying them of a better forum is definitely useful in my opinion. But I'll remember that next time I have a bug in the MSVC compiler. Wouldn't want to notify Microsoft about _that,_ would we? :-)

Comment: Really? I'd have more confidence in your assertion if you hadn't asked OP for clarification on that very issue :-) And the OP explicitly stated "I'm not completly sure if it's proper to ask this **here** ...". But we can debate this till the cows come home, why don't we just let the OP decide?